# WCF concurrency call

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

How can we limit the number of concurrent calls in wcf?

Comment: This article originally posted by @Ezombort answered OP's question: http://kennyw.com/indigo/150

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c7966a9a-1343-49e5-b5e9-7ce15b15ae70) for an example.  You have the ability to specify limits using properties on the [`ServiceThrottlingBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.aspx) class:

- MaxConcurrentCalls: Maximum number of messages actively processing across a ServiceHost object. Each channel can have one pending message that does not count against the value of MaxConcurrentCalls until Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) begins to process it.
- MaxConcurrentInstances: Maximum number of InstanceContext objects in the service that can execute at one time
- MaxConcurrentSessions: Maximum number of sessions a ServiceHost object can accept at one time

(These descriptions are taken from MSDN)